# Print PDF created using iTextG via. printer connected on ethernet?

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I have created a pdf using iTextG library. Now I would like to print it over ethernet. How should I achieve this? Using following lines, I can call default print service but it doesn't show my printer connected to ethernet. I am able to print the pdf using Google Cloud Print service after installing drivers on my PC. Can anyone help me on this?

Currently I am using following code:

```
public class MyPrintHelper {

    private Context context;

    public MyPrintHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void print() {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        // Set job name, which will be displayed in the print queue
        String jobName = context.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
        // Start a print job, passing in a PrintDocumentAdapter implementation
        // to handle the generation of a print document
        printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(), null);
    }

    private class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {

                input = new FileInputStream(new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), PDF_FILE_NAME));
                output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }


            PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Name of file").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

            callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
        }

    }
}
```

And to use the above helper class, I call it as follows:

```
MyPrintHelper helper = new MyPrintHelper(getActivity());
helper.print();
```

I am using following printer:

https://www.amazon.in/Heyday-Thermal-Receipt-Printer-GP-U80300I/dp/B011BWM95E

Comment: Your question is not about iText. Tag removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your device should be on the same network as the printer. Also, you need to ensure that the printer you're using is [Mopria-certified](https://www.android.com/versions/oreo-8-0/): "Integrated printing support
Compatible with all Mopria-certified printers, which make up 97% of printers sold worldwide."